# Creating a palette of mixed colours using PHP/GD

Tags: php, image, gd

An interesting problem has been presented by a client. They are looking to create an application that allows users to pick from a selection of colours and produce a dynamic image that shows a mix of the selected colours. The selected colours are randomly plotted on an image with varying shapes and placement.

The end product might look something like this

http://matsinc.com/mixologyapp/swatchimage.php?red1=71&green1=160&blue1=109&size1=1&pct1=0.3&colname1=Ocean%20Green&red3=30&green3=28&blue3=27&size3=1&pct3=0.5&colname3=Black&red5=234&green5=221&blue5=200&size5=1&pct5=0.2&colname5=Eggshell

The above link has 3 colours put into the image.

We were thinking of  having a grid where each block has a % chance of the colours provided showing. Then plot the image with a random offset from the grid location, with a random shape and size... then move off to the next element in the grid.

Has anyone tackled something like this before? What strategy did you attack the problem with?

Comment: What is your problem, exactly? Where do you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand your question, but the question of your client is fun.

I build an example with help of some other question here on stackoverflow, see: http://twitterbootstrapbuttons.w3masters.nl/randomimage.html

randomimage.html contains a form with tree color pickers (http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-colorpicker/):

```
<form action="" method="get" id="imageform">
    <div class="input-append color" data-color="#08c" data-color-format="hex">
    <input type="text" class="span2" value="#08c" name="color1" id="color1">
    <span class="add-on"><i style="background-color: #08c"></i></span>
    </div><br>
    <div class="input-append color" data-color="#08c" data-color-format="hex">
    <input type="text" class="span2" value="#08c" name="color2"  id="color2">
    <span class="add-on"><i style="background-color: #08c"></i></span>
    </div><br>
    <div class="input-append color" data-color="#08c" data-color-format="hex">
    <input type="text" class="span2" value="#08c" name="color3"  id="color3">
    <span class="add-on"><i style="background-color: #08c"></i></span>
    </div><br>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Generate your image"/>
</form>
```

on submit calls randomimage.php via jquery and shows the image (start with an empty image [Clear an IMG with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865689/clear-an-img-with-jquery)):

```
<script>    

    /*empty images from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865689/clear-an-img-with-jquery */

    $('#result1').attr('src', 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==');


    $('.color').colorpicker();
    $('#imageform').submit(function() { 

    $.get('randomimage.php',  { 'colors[]': [ $('#color1').val(), $('#color2').val(),  $('#color3').val() ]}, function(data) {
$('#result1').attr('src', 'data:image/png;base64,'+data);

}); 



        return false;
    });

</script>
```

randomimage.php builds the image based on [How can I make a noisy background image using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727450/how-can-i-make-a-noisy-background-image-using-php). The result is a base64_encode img string ([PHP HTML image output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695077/php-html-image-output)):

```
<?
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','on');
function ImageColorAllocateFromHex ($img, $hexstr) 
{ 
  $int = hexdec($hexstr); 

  return ImageColorAllocate ($img, 
         0xFF & ($int >> 0x10), 
         0xFF & ($int >> 0x8), 
         0xFF & $int); 
} 


//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695077/php-html-image-output
ob_start();
//random colored noise
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2727450/how-can-i-make-a-noisy-background-image-using-php
$x = 150;
$y = 150;
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($x,$y);
$colors = array();
foreach($_GET['colors'] as $color)
{
    $colors[]= ImageColorAllocateFromHex ($im, $color);
}   
$number = count($colors)-1;

for($i = 0; $i < $x; $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j < $y; $j++) {

        imagesetpixel($im, $i, $j, $colors[rand(0,$number)]);
    }
} 
imagepng($im);

$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo base64_encode($output);
exit;
```

have fun

Comment: hmm, only pixels, would be funner to be able to choose a shape / size for each color :)